# Building VS Project with Mono producing EXE

Tags: c#, mono

I'm a Mono newbie and I'm pretty confused. I'm using Xamarin Studio to compile a VS project. I've set the active runtime to Mono 4.5.

Confusion is that it's producing an EXE, but I was under the impression that with Mono you could build applications which can run on Linux.

Clarification would be lovely

Thank you

Comment: You run them with the command "mono yourcompiled.exe". It may surprise you but mono assemblies can be run on Windows too, and Linux can use file extensions just like windows although they really don't mean much in some cases.

Comment: Thank you Ron. Makes sense now.